# Why does the binding in the fragment under my Activity appear null when I set the night mode?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the `Viewpager` embedded `fragment` and I adapted to night mode. When I turned on night mode, I found that the activity was rebuilt, and of course the fragment was also.

Ngiht mode: `UiModeManager.setNightMode(android.app.UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

I would think they are reloading resources dedicated to night mode and reloading the view. But when I initialize the `recyclerView` (in one of the fragments), it is null.

If I put all the initialization in `onCreateView` it looks like it is initialized normally. But I call it from the activity, it is still null

`MainActivity`: [url](https://github.com/AugustToko/ACG-Player/blob/master/app/src/main/java/top/geek_studio/chenlongcould/musicplayer/activity/main/MainActivity.java)

```
// in MainActivity
if (isDarkMode) {
        PreferenceUtil.getDefault(MainActivity.this)
                .edit().putBoolean(Values.SharedPrefsTag.DARK_MODE, false).apply();
        UiModeManager UiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
        UiModeManager.setNightMode(android.app.UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        mMainBinding.navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.dart_mode).setChecked(false);
    } else {
        PreferenceUtil.getDefault(MainActivity.this)
                .edit().putBoolean(Values.SharedPrefsTag.DARK_MODE, true).apply();
        UiModeManager UiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
        UiModeManager.setNightMode(android.app.UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        mMainBinding.navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.dart_mode).setChecked(true);
    }

public final class MusicListFragment extends BaseListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "MusicListFragment";

    public FragmentMusicListBinding mMusicListBinding;

    private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void reloadData() {
        Data.sMusicItems.clear();
        Data.sMusicItemsBackUp.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mMusicListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_music_list, container, false);
        loadData();
        return mMusicListBinding.getRoot();
    }


    public void initRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity) {
            @Override
            protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
                return 700;
            }
        };
        linearLayoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(15);

        adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(mActivity, Data.sMusicItems
                , new MyRecyclerAdapter.Config(PreferenceUtil.getDefault(mActivity).getInt(Values.SharedPrefsTag
                .RECYCLER_VIEW_ITEM_STYLE, 0), true));
        mMusicListBinding.includeRecycler.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mMusicListBinding.includeRecycler.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mMusicListBinding.includeRecycler.recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(15);
        mMusicListBinding.includeRecycler.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    GlideApp.with(mActivity).resumeRequests();
                } else {
                    GlideApp.with(mActivity).pauseRequests();
                }
            }
        });
        mMusicListBinding.includeRecycler.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

When I set the night mode, `MainActivity` will call the `initRecyclerView()` method of `musicListActivity`, but he will have a null pointer. But it is normal for me to start the application normally.

Comment: can you post your complete activity code?. So I can help to resolve your issue...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code for mainActivity is[https://github.com/AugustToko/ACG-Player/blob/master/app/src/main/java/top/geek_studio/chenlongcould/musicplayer/activity/main/MainActivity.java](https://github.com/AugustToko/ACG-Player/blob/master/app/src/main/java/top/geek_studio/chenlongcould/musicplayer/activity/main/MainActivity.java) @RajeshVijayakumar